# Opencart + unique product with options + stock control

Tags: unique, opencart, stock

I make bracelets and place them in my opencart store. Each bracelet is unique, so I have 1 in stock. But customer has to let me know the size of his/her wrist so I can adapt it.

Options ask me for quantities. So, I can not use them because I must enter a number or the option does not become visible.

What I need is:

bracelet B ---> tell me your wrist´s size: (here a drop down or a text box to let the customer choose or write).

Order will reads: Bracelet B... Size: 18cm.... xx $

Then, when the customer pays, Bracelt B is out of stock.

Now, I can do all that, but any time a customer adds an option, the bracelet keeps available.
So Order reads:
Bracelet B ... Size: 18cm... xx$
Bracelet B ... Size: 19cm... xx$ etc

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
    quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }
            /*adding Shadyyx solution*/
            if (json['error']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="error" style="display: none;">' + json['error'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 

                $('.error').fadeIn('slow');
            }
            /*end adding*/
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: creating an `option` for product is best choice as per your requirements but u can use text fields also then for **outofstock** suggestion you should goto `setting` and then in `stock` option and also in product use `Subtract Stock` option yes

Comment: Hi Mudasirahanger! Thanks you your time and for sharing. I already did what you say, the problem is that if I do that, everytime a customer enter a wrist size, the bracelet is available. Because, when you add options, you have to say how many items do you have for that option. And I have 1 customizable according to customer wrist´s size. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In default OC You have the ability to disable ordering of *out of stock* products.

Simply go to the administration -> System -> Settings, click edit on Your store and navigate to the *Options* tab. Then scroll down to the *Stock* section and notice the *Stock Checkout:* option. If You select **No** and save the users won't be able to order the products that are not in stock.

This means that if You create a bracelet product with 1 piece in stock, add an option to it with one piece in stock and somebody order this one, it's stock will be immediately set to *Not in stock* and nobody will be able to order it again.

If You'd like to hide all the products that are not in stock after they are ordered, You have two options - either do this manually by disabling the product or You'd need to implement few modifications in to the `getProducts()` method for the product model to load only those products that are still in stock.

UPDATE regarding the comment: You are misunderstaning the options in OpenCart. One option for which You have the stock 1 piece is the size option, which may have different values, e.g. 15cm, 16cm, 17cm, 18cm, etc. All these values contained in one single size option for one single stock item mean that if I select any of them, after ordering the bracelet there will no more pieces left.

What You are telling is creating one option for 15cm with 1pcs stock, another option for 16cm with 1pcs stock, etc., thus having 1 piece in stock for each size - this is incorrect (i.e. misuse of product options). Nevertheless, even in this case, when different sizes have all one piece but the product itself has only one piece, after ordering first it should be out of the stock even there are options with stock left...

**Step by step walkthrough**:

1. Go to Your OC administration and log in.
2. Hover the mouse over the *Catalog* menu point and click on the *Options* entry
3. On this Options overview screen notice the **Insert** in the top-right corner - click it

   1. Enter the Option's name, e.g. *Wrist Size*
   2. Choose the Option's type, either *Select* or *Radio* (depending on how many possible values You want to have, more than 4, use *Select*)
   3. *Sort Order* may be a numeric value (or when blank, will be filled with 0)
   4. Now there is empty table underneath with one row containing only a button *Add Option Value* - by clicking this it will add a row with empty form fields to enter the Option's value; let's say we want to add wrist sizes from 15cm to 22cm => 8 values => click that button 8 times (be careful, after each click it will be moved downward as a new row with form fields will appear above it)
   5. into that 8 rows enter all the necessary values, e.g. *15cm*, *16cm*, ..., *22cm* as value's name and sort order to match Your needs (leaving blank may lead to inappropriately ordered values when displayed)
4. Click on *Save* button located at top-right corner.
5. Now navigate Yourself to the products overview, select the product You want to add this option to and click *Edit* in that row. Move to the *Data* tab and make sure the bracelet has these settings:

   - Quantity: 1
   - Subtract Stock: Yes
   - Out of Stock Status: Out of Stock
6. Then move to the Option tab and add the new option by typing the Option's name (*Wrist Size*) in the left area - after the Option is found, click on that label and a new Option (new tab) will be added to the view. Now make sure the Option is required and add all possible values while setting these settings to all of them:

   - Quantity: 1
   - Subtract Stock: Yes
7. The other option values depends on Your business model. Now Save the product and try to order it with any of the wrist sizes value. If You have the settings set for the store that the customer isn't possible to order the products that are out of stock, this should work for You.

Let me know if there is something that I missed (or if it still doesn't work).

**UPDATE**:

Here is one possible solution (not tested but I believe it will work out of the box or maybe there is only simple bug You may fix Yourself):

Open up the `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` and find this line (should be at 543):

```php
            $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option);
```

and **before this line directly** add this code (You may want to do this via vQmod extension):

```php
            if ($product_info['quantity'] == 1 && $product_info['subtract'] == 1) {
                $products = $this->cart->getProducts();
                $already_added = false;
                foreach ($products as $product) {
                    if ($product['product_id'] == $this->request->post['product_id']) {
                        $already_added = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ($already_added) {
                    return $this->response->setOutput(json_encode(array(
                        'error' => $this->language->get('text_product_already_added')
                    )));
                }
            }
```

Then open up this file `catalog/language/english/checkout/cart.php` and add this to the end:

```
$_['text_product_already_added'] = 'This product has allowed quantity of 1 piece and is already added to a cart. Remove it from the cart to be able to add it (e.g. with different size).';
```

This is all only as an example, You may edit the error message to meet Your requirements.

Warning: this is only a simple solution not letting the same user (or within the same session) to add the same product twice or more times into the cart but it won't prevent the same product being added and ordered at the very same time by two different users (or one user using two browsers, for example). For this edge case You'd need to implement some kind of *product locking* - after it is added to cart this is saved to a DB and nobody else would be able to add the same product into the cart. In this case it would be nice to store also the datetime when it was locked and have a cron job that will unlock this product (also with removing from the cart) so that the product is not locked for ever and is *orderable* by other users again...

**EDIT for JS part**:

Open up this file `catalog/view/javascript/common.js` and search for method `function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {` - in this file find this part:

```js
if (json['success']) {
    ...
}
```

and after this one add this code:

```js
        if (json['error']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="error" style="display: none;">' + json['error'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 

            $('.error').fadeIn('slow');
        }
```

This should be enough.

**UPDATE XYZ**:

In PHP find this code what have we added:

```
                    return $this->response->setOutput(json_encode(array(
                        'error' => $this->language->get('text_product_already_added')
                    )));
```

and change it to this (then try):

```
                    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode(array(
                        'error' => $this->language->get('text_product_already_added')
                    )));
                    return;
```

The point is to see in console where the request is done to `index.php?route=checkout/cart/add` the response with either `success` or `error` message in response. Try for both cases to make sure You are looking at the correct request (in success You can see the success message on the top of page so You may be sure it was done) and then try again to receive error (for the same product) message - it should be contained in the response the same way as the success message is. If still doesn't work, try to change `return;` to `exit;`...

Comment: Hi Shadyyx! I already did what you suggest. More than that, let me explain the real result of that: 1 bracelet + option (18cm, quantity1 - 19cm, quantity? 1)= 3 bracelets in stock. What I need is options without requesting quantity or a textbox to let the customer enter the wrist size. Thank you very much for your time, patiente and for sharing. If you have any clue, I will really appreciate it. Dafne

Comment: Hi Shadyyx! you are the first one that understand what I need. Your 1st paragraph in your update is exactly what I have to do. The second paragraph is what Opencart lets me do, and I know that is not wright. I did not find a way to make it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: My dear friend: I did step by step to be sure I was not making any mistake and the result is the same: if you order 1 bracelet 18cm, perfect, if you order another 18cm, perfect. The system says: out of stock. Buuuttt, if you order the 18cm  plus 16cm and 15 cm, you will have 3 bracelets on your cart. You can not order 2 of each, but one of each size. I have no word to thank you all your help and patiente. Thank you very, very much. Dafne

Comment: @user3476964 Hmm, then it looks like there is some kind of BUG in OC implementation or maybe I do not understand it either... I would expect if the product itself has quantity **only 1 piece** after ordering an option (which values also have quantity 1 piece) that the product's quantity is subtracted as well leading to the product's stock status **Out of Stock** not letting the customer to order it again with different option's value. But a real fix for this may not be that difficult - I'll take a look at it when I have little bit more time today.

Comment: Shadyyx, I think that the problem is that options ask you for quantities and stock asumes that it is part of the total stock. I mean, the "Quantity" column should not be there in this case. It is perfect when you have 10 bracelets, 3-18cm, 5- 17cm and 2-16cm. But not for my case. Thank you so much Shadyyx, you are really nice!

Comment: OK, I've tried it for myself in my demo shop... And...sadly...You are right!!!It is behaving like I described **but only if You place a product into a cart and checkout successfully**. If You only add the product to the cart it allows You to add each option unless there is only one piece of it in the cart... In this case the `addToCart` is not working properly - it should check the quantity and the quantity of current products in cart and not allow You to add more of them... Maybe I'll come up with some fix for You ;-)

Comment: Added some simple solution, please check the answer again.

Comment: Shadyyx: you will never know how much I appreciate your help and your time. Thank youuuu so much Shadyyx. I will try it and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: IT WORKKKKSSSS!!! I am so happy! the only little problem is that the error message does not show up. I tried to make it works but I could not. May be something really silly but I can not see the error. Thank you Shadyyx.

Comment: I'm afraid that the error message needs to be displayed separately. Unfortunately the JS method `addToCart` is responding only to `success` message forgetting about the `error` - I'll add this to my answer in few minutes.

Comment: And You do not need to thank all the time and repeatedly. We are here to help (if possible) answer the questions (if understandable) or to solve Your problems (if solvable within the programmatic scope). You can express Your thank by up-voting and accepting the answers (if helpful).

Comment: Hi Sadyyx! let me thank you please, as many times as I feel I need to do because is my only way to show my gratitude. THANKS :) Back to your last post, I added the code but nothing. May be I made a mistake. I will review step by step your directions again, just in case. :)

Comment: I am afraid the error message does not work Shadyyx. Just when you have a free minute, please, give me a hand. :) By the way, how do I vote you? I could not find anything about.

Comment: On the right to the answer You can see two triangles, one with the apex pointing to the top (for **upvoting**) and one with the apex pointing to the bottom (for **downvoting**). Between them is a number representing the absolute value of up- and down-votes. Below them You should be able to see a *tick* after clicking on which You are able to **accept** the best answer. Please, post in the original question Your whole `addToCart` JS method's code.

Comment: The system tells me that I have to be 15 "Idontknowwhat" to vote. I accepted your as best answer (it is indeed) and I will wait until I am 15 "Idontknowwhat" to vote you. I copied that part of the code into my original post.

Comment: Hmm, OK, You added the code correctly. Here, to be honest, I have no idea why the error message is not displaying. Can You inspect the console (Firebug, or in Chrome the Developer console) for the XHR (ajax) request when adding product to the cart? Is there the `error` text returned correctly?

Comment: Hi Shaddyx! I am afraid the error message does not want to be diplay. I inspected it but, it seems code does not exist or isn´t activated. There is no errors at all. I repeated step by step again, twice, and I can not figure out where is the problem. Uh??? :)

Comment: check the update XYZ...hope it's the last one as I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Shadyyx, this is really crazy, I run both, with the new and with the old paragrah and guest what? There is no message at all, no success no error in any situation. Mmmh, I think that the error message does not display because the success one does not either. I am not sure if when you add something to the cart there is a error in my main code. I will check it and let you know. :)

Comment: Ok, I fix the success message and made all the changes again, one by one. Error message does not work in none of the options. I analized it at the console and I got: {"error":"This product has allowed quantity of 1 piece and is already added to a cart. Remove it from the cart to be able to re-add it (e.g. with different size)."} in Answer and JSON. And there is a line4- jquery-1.7.1.min.js. Any idea? Shadyyx, I am feeling a little ashamed of being so "heavy". Please, forgive me.

Comment: Here is some jsFiddle I have created. I have simulated the conditions in OpenCart so You should get the point. I cannot help anymore better, now it's Your turn to find out what may be wrong. ;-) http://jsfiddle.net/k8rqg/1/

Comment: Thank you Shadyyx! I will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi Shadyyx! I am driving crazy with this. How could it be that your code works perfect since no second bracelet is added to cart if it is already there but the error message does not display. I tried everything! But, just a question, could it be that we should modify something in product page? I tried but of course I messes all up. :)

Comment: @user3476964 Open up my profile page, there You'll find my webpage, go there, switch to English, navigate to Contact page and send me a message with Your FTP credentials (and URL of Your store). I'll take a quick look at the code, request+response and try to finish this. (don't make this a habit - I am not doing this usually!)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment your post.

I had the problem with error message not showing up, when trying to add the product twice.

I needed to add the JS code to /catalog/view/theme/*/product/product.tpl

Just search for "url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'" and add the code shadyxx postet right after

```
if (json['success']) { ... }
```